# XCODE and OSX related

Tags: xcode, macos, passwords

When I start to debugging in XCode an IOS app at first time ask my OSX login password.
Why? This happens after the last OSX system update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's new additional security measure introduced by Apple to prevent malicious software from hooking into your processes. OS X now requires you to enter your root password to permit Xcode debugger attaching to processes.